# Using site1.com as like site2.com, with Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, subdomain

Please think about we have 2 site.

**site1.com** and **site2.com**

i want to upload my magento files to site1.com on my server..
but want to use it with http://shop.site2.com domain (which is in another server)

I must install ssl certificate to all sites; its ok.

But.. How will i direct shop.site2.com to site1.com

**I don't want anyone see site1.com's domain name, on http://shop.site2.com's any shopping steps**

Can i do it with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a database stored/xml files/any sort of data-storage system, and access data from that domain. .htaccess files will probably not work for what you need, because then people could steal data from other domains and sites using just .htaccess. .htaccess files are used to tell the server (seems like Apache in your case) where to redirect the browser and how to define file extensions etc.

Comment: by that way, i must install magento files to both 2 server; right? but i dont want to use site2.com's server; i dont want to upload anything to that server.

Comment: You may have to play with redirection domains etc., I think it's not a matter of files on server to my opinion.

Comment: but redirection of index page is not enough for me. i dont want anyone see site1.com's domain on any step of shopping.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need site1.com domain at all?

You can create a DNS A record for shop.site2.com that points to site1.com server IP.

You need magento only on server1.

If you are using https only for shop subdomain, you need a ssl certificate only on server1

Comment: so, may i see the links on shop.site2.com as like 'shop.site2.com/product.html'? for example: original site has url on index page like: site1.com/product.html.. i must see it in site2, as like shop.site2.com/product.html..

Comment: Yes, you will see shop.site2.com instead of site1.com.
You also need to configure the apache server on server1 to handle requests from shop.site2.com - set document root same as for site1.com